# send DM to user specified by command arg in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am making a bot for my server and want it to send a DM to a user, I know about `message.author.send("Your message here.")` but what I want is for it to be done via a command. E.G. `!dm {user} {message}`. how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you parse your arguments you can use this code within your command (make sure this is inside of an async function).

```js
let mention = args[1].match(/^<@!?(\d+)>$/)[1];
if (!mention) return message.channel.send('Invalid user.');

let recipient = await client.fetchUser(mention);
recipient.send(args.slice(2));
```

Comment: what is an async function

Comment: It should be declared using `async function(bot, message) {` or `async (bot, message) => {` (ES6).

Comment: You actually don't need to setup the mention regex yourself, you can also use: `message.mentions.users.first()`, but at the same time, `message.mentions.users` is not garantueed to be sorted, so this could actually be a nice workaround for that

Comment: If you allow mentioning your bot as another prefix (highly recommended), the first mention will be the bot and not the user and that's just hell to work out.